# S-box for byte substitution where the s-box values are multiplicative inverses of 257

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes

The title basically says it. We have a 16 by 16 s-box, $256$ entries total. And the first value is the multiplicative inverse of $257$, so

$1 \times k \bmod 257, \space k = 1$.

$2 \times k \bmod 257, \space k = 129$.

$3 \times k \bmod 257, \space k = 86$

$\ldots$

Would this be secure? and if the value is higher then $255$, then we choose the lowest unused number.

Comment: what about the entry of zero ? is it equal to zero?

Comment: @hardyrama yes, would that be a problem?

Comment: Fixed point . it will be good to calculate the DDT , LAT , BCT and compare it to AES sbox

Comment: Okay, But is just the sbox I described above good?

Comment: I personally see the question "is this a good sbox" to be similar to the question "is a hammer a good tool" - it rather depends on what you intend to use it for.  A hammer is good if you have a nail; it is less good if you're trying to paint a wall (a paintbrush works rather better in that case)

Comment: Secure if you use it in say, a blockcipher. It doenst really mater. Does it provide good diffusion etc?

Comment: "It doenst really matter"; actually, it does.  A specific block cipher depends certain things from an sbox; a different block cipher would depend on different things.  Certainly, there are some things that are common to most block cipher designs  (high nonlinearity, low differential probability), however there are other aspects (e.g. presence of fixed points) which may or may not be important.

Comment: @poncho okay, but could THIS s-box be vulnerable to linear/differential cryptanalysis? I dont know a lot about crypto, so forgive if this question sounds a bit, you know.

Comment: and the entries are multiplicative inverses mod 257 not of 257.